# Properly register and enqueue scripts in wordress - Issue getting scripts to work

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming

I've been working on a wordpress theme and I utilised different javascript elements within the site. I'm rather a rookie when it comes to Javascript and JQuery so I was inserting the scripts and cdn links directly into the `<head>` section of Header.php.

When some of my dropdown stopped working I realised it was creating a conflict between JQuery versions and that I'd been doing it wrong this whole time.

So I've learnt what I can regarding registering and enqueuing scripts but have had no luck getting the dropdowns etc up and running again.

Would you be able to tell from the code I've posted below what could be causing this issue? I know there's a high chance I've made a daft error with being new to it, I just can't fathom what it is.

These two snippets are the scripts for two repeated elements on the website. A slideout toggle box and a dropdown accordion box.

Accordion.js

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
collapsible: true, active: false
});
$('#accordion2').accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
 $('#accordion3').accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
```

});

Togglebox.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
  $( ".togglebox" ).toggle( "slide", 1000 );
    });
});
```

The following snippet is the code I've placed in my Functions.php file.

```
       function my_scripts_method() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-accordion',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
        array('jquery')
        );
    wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tabs.js',
    array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-toggle');
}
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

I've saved the 'accordion.js' and 'togglebox.js' file locally in the JS folder of the theme I'm using.

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 JS Files:

- accordion.js
- togglebox.js

Save the 2 Files in the JS Folder of your Theme. After that register and enqueue the scripts in the Functions.php File of your Theme.

You don't have to Register jquery and jquery ui there already included in Wordpress. Here two useful links for you:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

Try this in Togglebox.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
      $( ".togglebox" ).slideToggle( 1000 );
    });
});
```

Try this in functions.php:

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_register_script( 'custom-accordion', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js', array('jquery-ui-accordion'), '1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-accordion' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-togglebox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/togglebox.js', array('jquery'), '1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-togglebox');
```

Change custom in functions.php to the slug of your theme. I tried this code and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've done what you suggested and placed them in 2 files 'accordion.js' and 'togglebox.js'. Both are placed in the JS folder yet the scripts aren't working yet.

I've edited my original post to show the new code as I've adjusted it. I've only just done this so I'm still looking into solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've been reading through the documentation and I've made some amendments. I'm still not having any  luck with it. I have a javascript book here I'm going to check through to see if I can find anything.

I've edited my original post again in the meantime with the amendments.

Comment: I've changed it all again after finding out some new things. My accordion JS now works again as should, but I'm still having issue with the toggle JS not working.

I've amended the code in the post again for people to see.

Comment: Edited it a last time I hope it helps you.